# Is a call of the static method is a test case for unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

This is a simplified model of my class.

```
public static FooFactory
{
    public void CreateFooByUrl(string url) 
    {
        try 
        {
           // business logic
        }
        catch(Exception exc) 
        {
           ApplicationLogger.LogError(exc);
        }
    }
}
```

`ApplicationLogger` is a static class which is used across the solution. How can I verify that error was logged?

This is example of my test method.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateFooExpectedError()
{
    // Arrange
    string testUrl = "fakeUrl";

    // Act
    FooFactory.CreateFoo(testUrl);

    // Assert
    /ApplicationLogger.LogError();
}
```

How to check that `LogError` method was called? Does it a test case?

Comment: @mason but does it make sense to have the try catch block in there? I am in general not that happy with catch all methods

Comment: That would be a different question entirely, and I couldn't answer that without knowing a lot more about your application.

Comment: How is `ApplicationLogger` normally configured? Can you dynamically add log destinations?

Comment: @mason I agree, I think it should be part of the OP his question why the error should be thrown. I think a workflow that depends on error logging is a lots more dangerous one than a fail early workflow. From the structure here (no throw afterwards) I would rather see null errors occuring after `CreateFooByUrl` threw an error and foo wasn't created

Comment: @Icepickle True, the exception should probably be allowed to go up to wherever it can be handled, and really Exceptions probably shouldn't be used, but rather a request/response pattern. But I didn't address that as part of my answer, because I think learning the basic of IoC is the focus here. It's a good point though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a hard dependency on `ApplicationLogger`. That's not good. Now you can't test that `CreateFooByUrl` works without actually logging something. Instead, have it use an `IApplicationLogger` (an interface) and then you can provide a mock implementation of that interface as part of unit testing. This will probably mean you either need to make `FooFactory` non static (you can't have a non static method in a static class anyways like you've shown) or change `CreateFooByUrl` to accept an `IApplicationLogger` as a parameter (messier).

Here's the clean way:

```
public interface IApplicationLogger
{
    void LogError(Exception exception);
}

public class ApplicationLogger : IApplicationLogger
{
    public void LogError(Exception exception)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}

public class FooFactory
{
    private readonly IApplicationLogger _logger;

    public FooFactory(IApplicationLogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void CreateFooByUrl(string url) 
    {
        try 
        {
           // business logic
        }
        catch(Exception exception) 
        {
           _logger.LogError(exception);
        }
    }
}

//now for the unit test
public void TestCreate()
{
    //arrange
    var mockLogger = new Mock<IApplicationLogger>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    mockLogger.Setup(m => m.LogError(It.IsAny<Exception>()));

    var factory = new FooFactory(mockLogger.Object);

    //act
    factory.CreateFooByUrl("something that will cause exception");


    //assert
    mockLogger.Verify(m => m.LogError(It.IsAny<Exception>()));
}
```

This is much better from a Separation of Concerns perspective. Why should FooFactory care how things get logged? It just needs to be able to log things. That's why it's better to code against an interface. Then if you ever want to switch logging implementations you just have to create a new class that implements IApplicationLogger and everything will magically work.